# Insert and Update Function work on single button click in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, insert

I am trying to insert and update data using same button. I have created method(uniqueEmail()) to check the email address exist in table or not. Using this method I am trying to insert data if email is not preset.
here is my code please correct me where I am going wrong.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=register;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        if (uniqueEmail()==true)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "update registeruser set email='" + TextBox1.Text + "', password='" + TextBox2.Text + "' where email='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
        }
        else 
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into registeruser values('" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "')";
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
    public bool uniqueEmail()
    {
        string stremail;
        string querye = "select count(email) as email from registeruser";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querye, con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read()) 
        {
            try
            {
                stremail = dr["email"].ToString();
                return(stremail != "0");
                if (stremail != "0")
                {
                    //errlblemail.Text = "email already exist";
                    return false;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string message = "error";
                message += e.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                dr.Close();
            }
        }

        return true;


    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks fine, now what is the issue??

Comment: @nirmala your code is fine .Please write what is error?

Comment: If I register with existing emailid instead of updating the data its inserting one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the count of the particular emailId, not the total count.

Modify the code as below:

```
public static bool uniqueEmail(string email)
{
        string stremail;
        string querye = "select count(email) as email from register where 
        email = '" + email + "'";
        //Remaining Code
}

 public static void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        if (uniqueEmail(TextBox1.Text)) == true) 
       //Remaining Code
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot@Boney its working now. but I have a doubt why we are using this statement "return(stremail != "0");" as if condition is used. Please explain I am new to .net.

Comment: It is a C# expression that evaluates to a Boolean value. It is basically equivalent to the below piece of code:

    `if (stremail != "0") 
                return true; //Count(email) is not Zero. Email already present in DB. Do Update
    else
                return false; //Count(email) is Zero. New Email. Do Insert.`

Answer (score 0):

@nirmala you should replace method

```
public void EmailCheck()
{
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnData"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from EmailSignUp where EmailId= @EmailId", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", this.txtEmail.Text);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (dr.HasRows == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EmailId = " + dr[5].ToString() + " Already exist");
            txtEmail.Clear();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Things need to be done

1. Pass the Email Id while calling

   if (uniqueEmail()==true)

To

```
if (uniqueEmail(TextBox1.Text)==true)
```

2. And in **uniqueEmail** method chenage the query ()include where condition as below

   ```
   public bool uniqueEmail(email)
   {
   string stremail;
   string querye = "select count(email) as email from registeruser where email='" + email + "'";

   //your remaining code
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nirmala your code is correct only you need to put where clause to find the email id already exist in the Database.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=register;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        if (uniqueEmail()==true)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "update registeruser set email='" + TextBox1.Text + "', password='" + TextBox2.Text + "' where email='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
        }
        else 
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into registeruser values('" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "')";
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
    public bool uniqueEmail()
    {
        string stremail;
        string querye = "select count(email) as email from registeruser where email = '" +TextBox1.Text+ "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querye, con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read()) 
        {
            try
            {
                stremail = dr["email"].ToString();
                return(stremail != "0");
                if (stremail != "0")
                {
                    //errlblemail.Text = "email already exist";
                    return false;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string message = "error";
                message += e.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                dr.Close();
            }
        }

        return true;


    }
}
```